# C# - How to calculate ASN.1 DER encoding of a particular hash algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

Given a hash algorithm like SHA1 or SHA256 how would I go about obtaining the ASN.1 DER encoding for it as defined in RFC3447? (see page 42 - [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt)) Below is the desired output.

```
MD5        30 20 30 0c 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05 05 00 04 10
SHA-1      30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14
SHA-256    30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20
SHA-384    30 41 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 02 05 00 04 30
SHA-512    30 51 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 03 05 00 04 40
```

I'm hoping there is some intelligent way to do this in C# that doesn't require me to write an Oid to ASN.1 DER conversion routine (or hardcode them). Any ideas?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "given a hash algorithm". Do you mean given the hash algorithm name as a string? You can convert from the dotted string Oid notation to bytes, but you'd still need a hardcoded mapping of the common hash algorithm Oids.

Comment: Input could be a HashAlgorithm, a string, or an Oid. The desired result is a a byte[] that matches the encoded format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will get you part of the way:

```
string oidString = CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID(hashName); // f.x. "MD5"
byte[] encodedOid = CryptoConfig.EncodeOID(oidString); // Gives you f.x. 06 08 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 02 05
```

Then you just need to insert it in the SEQUENCE-heading (`30<length>30<length2><oid>050004<hashlength>`).

Of course if you want to create an RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 signature, you would be better off just using [`RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bt3d03e.aspx).

---

*EDIT:* A few more details:

The ASN.1 you want to encode is this:

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
      digestAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
      digest OCTET STRING
}
```

where

```
AlgorithmIdentifier  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
      algorithm               OBJECT IDENTIFIER,
      parameters              ANY DEFINED BY algorithm OPTIONAL  
}
```

So to start from inside: the digest-AlgorithmIdentifier consist of a `SEQUENCE`-tag (30), a length (we will get back to that), an OID and some parameters. The OID for f.x. SHA-1 is 1.3.14.3.2.26, which is encoded as `06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a` (OID-tag 06, length 5 and the encoding of the OID). All the usual hash functions have NULL as parameters, which is encoded as `05 00`. So the AlgorithmIdentifier contains 9 bytes - this is the  above.

We can now continue with the rest of the DigestInfo: an OCTET STRING, which contains the value of the hash. SHA-1's 20 bytes hash will be encoded as `04 20 <HASH>`.

The length of the contents of the DigestInfo is now 11+22 bytes (). We need to start the DigestInfo with the `SEQUENCE`-tag, so we end up with: `30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0w 02 01 1a 05 00 04 20 <HASH>`.

If you need to generate it yourself, you should now be able to see that length2 = encodedOid.Length + 2 and that length = length2 + 2 + 2 + hashlength.

If you need some more information about encoding ASN.1, I can recommend Burt Kaliski's [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html).