# Why can't I verify signature with PKCS#11?

Tags: c#, .net-core, pkcs#11, pkcs#7, softhsm

Consider, I have created PKCS#7 message:

```
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(someByteArrayToSign);
SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo);

var certificateFromFile = new X509Certificate2("myCert.pfx");

var signer = new CmsSigner(certificateFromFile);
signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26");
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);

var myCmsMessage = signedCms.Encode();
SendBytesOverNetwork(myCmsMessage);
```

Now, I'd like to very signature. The following scenario works (using `BounceCastle` and `PKCS11.Interop`):

```
var signedPayloadCms = new CmsSignedData(GetBytesFromNetwork());

var data = (byte[])signedPayloadCms.SignedContent.GetContent();
byte[] signature = null;

foreach (SignerInformation signer in signedPayloadCms.GetSignerInfos().GetSigners())
{
    if (signature != null)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Multiple signature");
    }

    signature = signer.GetSignature();
}

var algCkm = CKM.CKM_SHA1_RSA_PKCS;
var mechanism = new Mechanism(algCkm);
Session.Verify(mechanism, somePublicKey.Handle, data, signature, out var isValid)
//isValid  == true
```

But when I use `CKM_RSA_PKCS` and manually calculate HASH, something is wrong:

```
var algHash = CKM.CKM_SHA_1;
var dataHash = Session.Digest(new Mechanism(algHash), data);

var algCkm = CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS;
var mechanism = new Mechanism(algCkm);
Session.Verify(mechanism, somePublicKey.Handle, dataHash, signature, out var isValid)
//isValid  == false
```

What I am missing? Why manually calculated hash is not valid?

Comment: You trying to verify a signature with a different algorithm to that used to sign it?

Comment: What do you mean by different algorithm? Both are The same - RSA, but first is proceed with sha1 digest. In second case I am doing it manually. Where is The  difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that hash needs to be wraped with *DigestInfo* structure. The simplest ways to do is to add prefix: (prefix valid only for SHA-1 hashes):

```
var dataHash = Session.Digest(new Mechanism(algHash), data);
dataHash = HexToByteArray("30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14")
             .Concat(dataHash).ToArray();

 var algCkm = CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS
...
```

Found in RF3447C: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt

How to create `DigestInfo` by self: [C# - How to calculate ASN.1 DER encoding of a particular hash algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713774/c-sharp-how-to-calculate-asn-1-der-encoding-of-a-particular-hash-algorithm)