# Digital Signature in Python Without ASN.1 Encoding?

Tags: python, openssl, rsa, digital-signature, asn.1

We need to generate a digital signature *without* ASN.1 encodings for verification by a downstream application. We can do this with openssl on the command line via:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey keyfile < hash
```

However, when I attempt a digital signature in Python (using the PyCrypto library), I am not able to do so without the the library including the ASN.1 encodings (that is, unless I fork PyCrypto to allow me to remove them). The rsa library also does not allow for this. Are there any Python crypto libraries or commands I've missed that permit this kind of flexibility?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/943972/what-is-the-difference-between-openssl-pkeyutl-sign-and-openssl-rsautl-sign), the OpenSSL command you show produces a `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` signature, which always contains an ASN.1 DER encoded structure by definition: your assumption is not really valid.

However, it is not necessary nor recommended for the receiver to implement a full DER parser when the hash algorithm is fixed. It can just check that a certain byte string is present (along with some other padding bytes, and before checking the digest at the rightmost position). [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713774/c-sharp-how-to-calculate-asn-1-der-encoding-of-a-particular-hash-algorithm) shows the DER encoding for the most popular digest algorithms.

If you really don't want to have ASN.1 in your signatures, you can only switch to [`RSASSA-PSS`](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_pss.html).